# Qual é o equivalente ao present perfect do inglês no português?

Tags: tradução-inglês, tempo-verbal

A língua inglesa tem um tempo verbal chamado *present perfect*. Esse é usado quando algo começou no passado e é contínuo ou ainda há relevância no hoje. Por exemplo:

> I've worked for 5 years at XYZ Global.

É a junção do verbo `to have` com o particípio do verbo em questão, no caso o `to work`. A frase que utilizei deve dar a entender que eu ainda trabalho na XYZ Global.

No exemplo a seguir, a leitura de João ainda tem relevância no presente.

> João has read the book we were talking about.

Há um equivalente na língua portuguesa de dê a mesma conotação?

Comment: nesse caso, eu usuaria: eu estou trabalhando na XYZ Global há 10 anos.
João está lendo o livro que estamos comentando.

Comment: No segundo exemplo, parece-me uma ação acabada - e não continuada; que é diferente da primeira.

Comment: No segundo exemplo é exatamente a mesma coisa em português: O João tem lido o livro do qual estamos falando. Ou seja, é a indicação do passado sem sem dizer quando: O João leu o livro a semana passada.

Comment: Mas cuidado: nem sempre o presente prefect se traduz por ter + verbo (tempo composto) em português, As vezes sim e as vezes não. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Em português, pode-se dizer que o **presente perfect** corresponde ao **Pretérito Perfeito Composto do Indicativo**: tenho falado, temos visto, etc.

I **have been** to the beach a lot recently.

**Tenho ido** muito à praia recentemente.

[Cyber Dúvidas - Tempos Compostos](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/tempos-compostos/8349)

As duas frases em inglês estão no present perfect, e os tempos podem ser traduzidos usando o tempo composto em português:

have worked=ter trabalhado
have read = ter lido

No pretérito perfeito o verbo auxiliar fica no presente do indicativo.

Tudo isso, porém, não implica que se traduz sempre o present perfect pelo pretérito perfeito composto do indicativo. Muitas vezes, sim. Eis uma resposta simples que não cobre todas as circunstâncias imagináveis.

Comment: O exemplo com o verbo "to be" leva à uma interpretação gramatical errada. No exemplo da pergunta, "I've worked for 5 years at XYZ Global", a tradução seria simplesmente "Eu trabalhei por 5 anos na Global XYZ". Não há equivalente ao present perfect em português. Por isso, aliás, é algo tão difícil de entrar na cabeça do estudante de inglês. A tradução de "eu tenho trabalhado há 5 anos na Global XYZ" em inglês teria que ser "I've been working for 5 years at XYZ Global", e não "I've worked". "I've worked" significa que acabou, não trabalho mais.

Comment: Desculpa mas: Tenho trabalhado na Globo pode ser: I've been working ou I've worked. ***Depende do contexto***. ***I've worked não significa que acabou***. ***Significa passado não específico***. I've worked here for five years: estou trabalhando aqui há cinco anos. Nos exemplos que dei na minha resposta, o presente perfect se traduz pelo tempo composto em português. Mas é verdade que isso não é sempre o caso. I've been to the beach a lot lately: Tenho ido a praia muito nos últimos tempos/recentemente.

Comment: I've been to the beach a lot recently does not mean  you are not going now. It just means past tense at the time of uttering the sentence. Just like in Portuguese  in this particular example.

Comment: Você fala português de Portugal ou do Brasil? No português do Brasil "eu tenho trabalhado" não é passado nem a pau.

Comment: Enrico, como eu falei, as vezes o presente prefect se traduz pelo tempo composto Ter + verbo, as vezes não. Claro. O que coloquei na minha resposta está certo. Naquele caso que citei (as minhas frases), a tradução da frase em inglês sai no tempo composto. Eu tenho ido muito a  praia, agora já não vou tanto. Esse tenho ido tem uma certa ideia de passado no momento de falar/da locução. Em qualquer português. Eu aprendi português no Brasil, mas já passei muito tempo em Portugal também.

Comment: Lambie, o teu primeiro exemplo está perfeito. Mas, "tem lido" não funciona para o exemplo da pergunta "João has read the book". A interpretações possíveis de "João tem lido o livro" são do tipo "João tem lido o livro todos os anos (ele adora esse livro)" ou "João tem lido o livro aos bocadinhos (ele anda com falta de tempo); e essa atividade tem continuado até recentemente; "João has read the book", pelo contrário, significa que ele já o leu todo, possivelmente só uma vez, e possivelmente há muito tempo.

Comment: Jacinto my friend, "John has read the/that book every year [at this point in time or time of speaking during the present year] he loves it so much". and "John has read the book little by little, not all at once". [unspecified but past]   It's the same thing in both languages. And careful with the idea that "John has read the book" meaning he has read the  whole book, **possibly once and possibly a long time ago**.   It means ***at the time of speaking*** some x happened in the past. Just like in Portuguese for this example.

Answer (score 2):

Esta é uma pergunta bastante recorrente para falantes de português que estão aprendendo inglês, e vice-versa.

Primeiramente vamos rever os conceitos do present perfect em inglês. **Present perfect**: este tempo verbal possui a estrutura "to have" no simple present + past participle do verbo principal; seu uso é encontrado na gramática inglesa para se referir a uma ação no passado que tem relevância com o presente, assim como foi dito na pergunta, o que corresponde ao aspecto "perfeito". Cuidado, porém, com o termo "contínuo". Este tempo verbal, pode sim, indicar continuidade, mas é diferente do "present perfect continuous" (ou "present perfect progressive"). O primeiro exemplo indica bem esse aspecto perfeito: I've worked for 5 years at XYZ Global.

Em português, há duas formas de traduzir o "presente perfeito": por *estrutura* e por *significado*. Por estrutura, o **Pretérito Perfeito Composto** é a substituição ideal. Ou seja, "I have worked" se torna "Eu tenho trabalhado", e o primeiro exemplo é livremente traduzido como "Eu tenho trabalhado por 5 anos na XYZ Global". O significado desta frase em português claramente indica que a ação começou no passado (5 anos atrás) e se estende até o presente. Note, porém, que em inglês, o **present perfect continuous** traduziria melhor esta ideia: I have been working for 5 years at XYZ Global - e aí sim não há correspondência alguma em português.

Agora quando olhamos para o segundo exemplo, "João has read the book we were talking about", a tradução livre forneceria "João tem lido o livro sobre o qual nós estávamos falando", o que não se encaixa bem dentro da língua portuguesa. Neste caso, deve ser observado que ainda que o "present perfect" funcione bem na língua inglesa, este tempo verbal tem mais uma característica: ele difere do **simple past** quanto à ausência de uma marcação temporal específica; ou seja, ninguém sabe quando João leu o livro, só sabemos que ele o leu. Em Inglês, duas estruturas válidas seriam: "João has read the book we were talking about" (o exemplo com present perfect) ou "Last week, João read the book we were talking about" (simple past, com marcação temporal).

Dito isso, a tradução deste último exemplo para o português é melhor feita com uso do **pretérito perfeito** (aqui entra a tradução por significado): João leu o livro sobre o qual nós estávamos falando. Lembre-se que a gramática portuguesa não exige a marcação temporal nesta frase, como faz a gramática inglesa. Assim, "João leu" significa que João leu e ponto; se uma informação temporal é adicionada, muito bem; se não, sem problemas.

Resumindo: o present perfect apresenta a mesma estrutura do pretérito perfeito composto em português, mas por vezes a melhor tradução é feita com o passado simples (para manter o significado original da frase).

Comment: Esta é a única resposta aceitável; mas poderias ser mais claro. O que tu chamas "tradução livre" ou "por estrutura" (*have read* = tenho lido*) é normalmente uma tradução errada. Nalguns casos até pode encaixar na língua portuguesa: p.ex. "João tem lido a Bíblia" (ele lê uns capítulos todos os dias); mas é muito diferente de "João has read the Bible".

Answer (score -1):

> Tenho trabalhado para a XYZ Global há cinco anos.
>
> João tem lido esse tipo de literatura de que estamos falando.

Não há um tempo verbal sintético para isso, é preciso usar a combinação Ter(presente do indicativo)+verbo principal(particípio). Mas, pensando bem, o inglês também não tem um tempo verbal sintético para isso - aliás, não tem tempo verbal sintético para quase nada...

Comment: Esperto! no segundo exemplo trocaste "o livro" por "esse tipo de literatura", que se presta melhor a complemento de *tem lido*. "O João tem lido a Bíblia" até está bem, mas é diferente de "João has read the Bible".

Comment: Não sei por quê, talvez diferença entre Portugal e Brasil, mas não me entra bem na cabeça "tenho trabalhado na X há cinco anos"; ainda menos "[...] por cinco anos", como já vi. Eu diria "tenho trabalhado na X desde 2013/desde há cinco anos". Mas a minha tradução preferida é "**trabalho** na X há cinco anos".